# Amazon WorkMail timeout .net core SmtpClient

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, smtp, smtpclient, amazon-workmail

I am trying to send a standard email message through AWS WorkMail using the SmtpClient in .NET Core. The configuration is very standard according to Amazon Documentation:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/general/latest/gr/workmail.html

```
  "Smtp": {
    "MailServer": "smtp.mail.eu-west-1.awsapps.com",
    "MailPort": "465",
    "SenderName": "Us us us",
    "FromAddress": "email@domain.com",
    "Username": "email@domain.com",
    "Password": "Password1$",
    "EnableSsl": "true"
  },
```

The settings are injected and the SmtpClient gets properly instantiated and the sending of the email is just:

```
        var mail = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(_smtpSettings.FromAddress, _smtpSettings.SenderName),
            SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            Body = message,
            Subject = subject,
            Priority = MailPriority.High
        };
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(sendToEmail));

        _smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Sadly, the sending always fails with a gateway timeout. We tried switching for 587 for STARTTLS and providing the Username without the domain (@). The server sending has proper SSL certificate installed and the mailserver is exactly the one we have our smtp on. Although this would not be a relevant solution, I also increased the timeout to 10 seconds (even though this would not be a solution).

Any idea what could be wrong? I am tearing my hair already. Seems to be an issue with AWS WorkMail.

Comment: Have you properly configured your SMTP gateway per the instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/smtp-gateway.html ?

Comment: No I have not done that but what would in this case be the gateway address and port?

Comment: Why would I do it, I thought its for rerouting traffic through own smtp server and I am just trying to poke the amazon default workmail endpoint to send an email for me

Comment: Well, just offering the suggestion to those docs since you're timing out against it. You might also check the SMTP connection example at the bottom of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/using_IMAP_client.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the default .NET Core SmtpClient does not support StartSSL (implicit SSL) which is the only accepted option by WorkMail. You see, WorkMail allows only connections that start from SSL and the SmtpClient first starts from unencrypted and then switches over to encrypted if it cannot connect.

If you are trying this, you will not get this to work using standard SmtpClient and as usually the case with Microsoft, they don't recognize it as an issue. You can either try tunneling or better just use one of the available libraries. Sadly, most of them are paid, there is AIM but it doesn't work with .NET Core and I didn't want to spend time porting not my own library to .NET Standard so I ended up using Mailkit.

There are some issues with the library though, first, before sending you have to call Connect which takes host and port as parameter, that means you cannot just inject premade smtpclient as singleton and have to instantiate it within the place of usage. That's dope and no interface also makes it unmockable which might blow your integration tests. Moreover, you have to do an ugly line before calling send like so:

```
emailClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
```

But at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the existing comment. SMTPClient is actually obsolete/deprecated but is not being marked as so. See comments here (https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/2986#issuecomment-430805681)

Essentially it boils down to SmtpClient hasn't been updated in years and is missing many features. The .NET Core team wanted to mark it as obsolete, but some developers have existing projects with "Warnings as Errors" turned on. It would instantly make any project that is using SmtpClient with Warnings as Errors turned on suddenly stop building. So... It's kinda deprecated, but not being marked so in some official docs.

MailKit is actually being pushed by Microsoft full stop for people to use when it comes to Email. Much to some developers chargrin who don't want to use a third party library for such a "simple" and common feature. Just in my personal experience, I think Mailkit is great and super easy to use. A quick guide to getting up and running is here : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/02/using-mailkit-send-receive-email-asp-net-core/